# Cannot convert String to Double in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary as a response from server:

```
{ 
  "gross_price" = "6.00";
  "gross_price_total" = "6.00";
  "guests_count" = 1;
}
```

Then I try:

```
 let x = dictionary["gross_price_total"] as? Double
 let y = dictionary["gross_price_total"]!
 println("result: \(x) \(y)")
```

As an output I get:

```
result: nil 6.00
```

Why? Is it not a `Double`?

It results that my final code doesn't work:

```
if let grossPriceTotal = dictionary["gross_price_total"] as? Double {
    println("final result: \(grossPriceTotal)")
}
```

Comment: `"6.00"` is a string, not a number. And if you search for "Swift string to double" then you should find some answers, some are already in the "Related" section ...

Answer (score 2):

This should let you going:

```
let x = (dictionary["gross_price_total"] as NSString).doubleValue
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension where you can initialize your Double with a String. But you have to use the NSString-method `doubleValue`:

```
extension Double{
    init(string:String){
        self = (string as NSString).doubleValue
    }
}

let x = Double(string: dictionary["gross_price_total"])
```

Comment: Upvote for a creative way of using the exentions